# Convert one-to-many relationship to one-to-one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, A and B
Table A:
Id int
Id_B int (FK with B)

Table B:
Id

Current state: An Id in table A can have multiple Id_B relationships, and two Id from table A can have the same Id_B

New state: I wish to make it so that two Id from table A cannot have the same Id_b. If I find such a relationship then create a new Id in table B and link it to the Id in table A to enforce the aforementioned constraint

I am lost on where to begin with this in SQL.

Before

Table A

| Id | Id_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

Table B

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

After (since there were two occurrences of 1 in the Id_B column, I created a new row in table B (with id 5), and assigned the Id of this to the Id 2 in table A to enforce uniqueness)

Table A

| Id | Id_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

Table B

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Comment: Ordinarily we decompose a M:M into two 1:M by creating a table that sits between A and B (called AB maybe) and it maps As to Bs. It might eventually acquire more columns and become a "proper" table in its own right rather than just a mapping A:B

Comment: Your requirement didn't change enough to remove the `M:M` requirement.  You can handle the constraint by adding `UNIQUE (id_b)` in the `M:M` mapping table, so that no `(id_a, id_b)` pair will use a particular `id_b` more than once.  Make sure you add that `M:M` mapping table.

Comment: That said, what I cannot see here is the M:M; for TableA to have an ID_B column it means that an A can map to only one B. One B can be mapped to many different A but there doesn't appear to be an M:M mechanism. How does any given A row link to multiple rows in B? Have you disabled primary keying in A such that you have two A rows with the same ID value, that have different ID_B values, and you're treating them as "the same A row" based on the ID value alone?

Comment: *I wish to make it so that two Id from table A cannot have the same Id_b* - then you're looking to make A:B 1:1 or 1:0..1 if ID_b can be null? I think perhaps you need to consider what relationship you want these tables to have (and it might be helpful to call them their real names too if they're helpful; it's a lot easier to visualize an object graph mapping between Orders and Products than A and B..)

Comment: I've updated the example to show how table A can have the same Id pointing to two different Id from table B

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all duplicate A.B_ID rows, add new B rows for the duplicates and update the corresponding A.B_ID.

Start with a query like:

```
with q as 
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by B_ID, order by ID) rn
  from A
)
select * 
from q
where rn > 1
```

2. Add a unique constraint on A.B_ID